# Howto refactor growing class in php?

Tags: php, oop, refactoring

I have a class that's growing past overview. It's the engine of a framework doing db, blob, file operations and more.

The class is being used heavily from different components and I don't want to refactor the monolithe into sub-classes since too much code around it would break.

I could live with

```
class engine {
  include 'core/db.php';
  include 'core/blob.php';
  include 'core/profiler.php';

  function __construct($config..) {
  }
}
```

with core/db.php containing methods as in

```
<?php
function dbPrepare($sql,$args) {
  ...
} 
...
```

I could live with the result, but PHP won't let me throw in an include where it expects a function.

Any solution for this? (I've touched the idea of letting the engine rebuild itself based on changes in sub-components but discarded the mess).

[image]

Comment: What exactly the problem?

Comment: @AlexBlex Class just passed 1500 rows. It's becoming clumbsy.

Comment: You could use traits. It wouldn't make it less horrible though. Refactor instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to assemble your class. Basically you declare the traits one per file as such

**core/db.php**

```
trait Db
{
    public function dbPrepare($sql, $args)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function dbSomethingElse() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**core/blob.php**

```
trait Blob
{
    public function blobMeBabyOneMoreTime()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then assemble them in your main file (**engine.php**)

```
require 'core/db.php';
require 'core/blob.php';

class engine {
    use Db;
    use Blob;
}
```

PS: You should look into autoloading and namespaces and avoid including files manually.

Comment: This turned out very well. Slight missuse of traits but very good code overview.